# Selective form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have multiple submit buttons in a form and I'm looking to disable jquery validation on all but one. This is probably easy but I've never encountered it before. Here is a simple example.

**Example:**

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" name="navigate" value="back">Back</button>
    <button type="submit" name="navigate" value="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

How would I validate only on the next button but not the back button?

Comment: try using foolproof http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MattBodily Looks promising thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: are you using a plugin for validation or do you handle it yourself before submitting via jquery?

Comment: You cannot do what you want.  The jQuery Validate plugin will be triggered by any `type="submit"` input or button contained within the form.   You can move the others outside of the form element OR change the others into `type="button"`.

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky. I ended up making it a button and posting it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the next button to `type="button"` and posting manually on click.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem then use this code block.

```
$("button [value='next']")
```

for select next button only?

Comment: It will still validate on either